# Access is denied error accessing WCF service

Tags: wcf, .net-4.5

I have a WCF service migrated to .Net framework 4.5 which is installed in IIS 7.0. I am able to browse the service in a browser. But when i refer the service in say a console application and try to call a method in it, i get the error "Access is denied". Below is the stack trace and web.config settings i am using.

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Access is denied.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at ConsoleApplication1.sharedservice.IShared.ProcessRequest(ProcessRequestRequest request)
       at ConsoleApplication1.sharedservice.SharedClient.ConsoleApplication1.sharedservice.IShared.ProcessRequest(ProcessRequestRequest request) in c:\Users\vijayara\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Service References\sharedservice\Reference.cs:line 214
       at ConsoleApplication1.sharedservice.SharedClient.ProcessRequest(String RuleName, String RequestMessage, Int32 WaitTime, Int32 ChannelID, Int32 PassThruMode, Int32 MaxResponseSize, Int32 MaxErrorText, Int32& ActualResponseSize, String& Response, Int32& ActualErrorTextSize, String& ErrorText) in c:\Users\vijayara\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Service References\sharedservice\Reference.cs:line 226
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\vijayara\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 22
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 

<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5">

          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          </assemblies>

        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
        <controls>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
      </pages>

      <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
      </httpHandlers>
      <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </httpModules>


    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      <modules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </modules>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Access_Shared_WCF.SharedBehavior" name="Access_Shared_WCF.Shared">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Access_Shared_WCF.IShared">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http/localhost/Access_Shared_WCF/Shared" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Access_Shared_WCF.SharedBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: remove the following config and try <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>

Comment: @Dhawalk That does not solve the problem.

Comment: have you tried debugging with the wcf test client, or using SoapUI or an equivalent?

Comment: Try adding traces to the server to see if you get any information. For example see a similar post here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/8c8763d0-1512-4412-a6e8-a21da94a406b/

Comment: I enabled trace both on server and Client, request does not reach the server it seams, i get Access denied error in the client itself, from the trace i am not able to find where exactly the access is denied.

Answer (score 2):

I have similiar issue with WCF. The problem was my appPool account doesn't have rights for generated assemblies by IIS which he use for "shadow copy". 
I track it down by using procmon http://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx with filtering to IIS process name  "w3wp.exe" and status to "access denied". Then call service again and check procmon output which files have this issue.

I have access deniend at c:\windows\temp\Microsoft.Generated.dll so I have remove it, call again and new one was generated and all works.

Another option is set "stronger" user identntiy to appPool like LocalService ( appPool -> advanced settings -> Indetitiy -> Predefined account -> Local service )

But solution with procmon is more fun :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why you can get this error.  The times I have encountered it are when the wcf method is secured to a specific AD role:

1. Setting the ClientCredentials on the web service client.  This can be finicky and doing certain things to the client connection can cause you to lose the credentials.
2. setting the InnerChannel.OperationTimeout before setting the ClientCredentials will wipe out the ClientCredentials (wierd I know, but I tested it many times).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be an issue where the service attempts to use event log to record information. The event log doesn't exist, the Application Pool Identity pseudo-user  does not have permission to *create* an event log. So the suggestions to use a high privileged account side step the issue by allowing it to be created. It may be possible to simply swap the user to a high account run and then switch back to regular.

Alternatively using powershell you can directly create the event log if you know what needs to be created (note it is usually very easy to view the source of any .NET application or dll to locate const string names to the usage)

```
 New-EventLog -source "My.Name.Space" -logname "MyApplicationName"
```

Source: https://robertgreiner.com/wcf-azure-service-bus-access-is-denied-exception/